# increment a value in rows with specific Column with python

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oHVO.png)   what i need to to ist to increment the ID based on the Value in column Country i used this
code:

`i=1 for row in new_cols5): new_cols5.loc[new_cols5.Country=='Germany','ID']='GR'+str(i) new_cols5.loc[new_cols5.Country=='Italy', 'ID']='IT'+str(i) new_cols5.loc[new_cols5.Country=='France','ID']='FR'+str(i) i+=1`

What i get is always the same number concatinated to the ID

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| GR1 | Germany |
| FR2 | France |
| IT3 | Italy |
| GR1 | Germany |
| FR2 | France |
| IT3 | Italy |

desired output:

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| GR1 | Germany |
| FR1 | France |
| IT1 | Italy |
| GR2 | Germany |
| FR2 | France |
| IT2 | Italy |
| GR3 | Germany |
| FR3 | France |
| IT3 | Italy |
| GR4 | Germany |
| FR4 | France |
| IT4 | Italy |

i would appreciate your help.

the Dataset look like this :

Comment: Can you provide the dataset? It will be easier for others to look!

Comment: First you could use `print()` to see what you get with `new_cols5.loc[]`. Command `new_cols5.loc[]` gives you all matching rows and you assing the same value to all rows at once. So you would have to iterate these rows to assign different values - or you should get number of matching rows to create list `["ID1", "ID2", ..."]` and assign this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could use `print()` to see what you get with `new_cols5.loc[]`.

`new_cols5.loc[]` gives you all matching rows and you assign the same value to all rows at once.

You would have to iterate these rows to assign different values.

Or:

You should get number of matching rows to create list `["GR1", "GR2", ..."]` and assign this list. And this doesn't need `for`-loop

```
matching = new_cols5.loc[new_cols5.Country=='Germany']

count = len(matching)

ids = [f"GR{i}" for i in range(1, count+1)]

new_cols5.loc[new_cols5.Country=='Germany', 'ID'] = ids
```

or using only mask with `True`/`False` and `sum()` which treads `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`

```
mask = (new_cols5.Country == 'Germany')

count = sum(mask)

ids = [f'GR{i}' for i in range(1, count+1)]

new_cols5.loc[new_cols5.Country == 'Germany', 'ID'] = ids
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

# --- columns ---

data = {
    'ID': ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'], 
    'Country': ['Germany','France','Italy','Germany','France','Italy','Germany','France','Italy'], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

# --- version 1 ---

matching = df.loc[df.Country=='Germany']
count = len(matching)
ids = [f"GR{i}" for i in range(1, count+1)]
df.loc[df.Country=='Germany', 'ID'] = ids

print(df)

# --- version 2 ---

count = sum(df.Country == 'France')
ids = [f'FR{i}' for i in range(1, count+1)]
df.loc[ df.Country == 'France', 'ID' ] = ids

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  ID  Country
0  A  Germany
1  B   France
2  C    Italy
3  D  Germany
4  E   France
5  F    Italy
6  G  Germany
7  H   France
8  I    Italy

# version 1

    ID  Country
0  GR1  Germany
1    B   France
2    C    Italy
3  GR2  Germany
4    E   France
5    F    Italy
6  GR3  Germany
7    H   France
8    I    Italy

# version 2

    ID  Country
0  GR1  Germany
1  FR1   France
2    C    Italy
3  GR2  Germany
4  FR2   France
5    F    Italy
6  GR3  Germany
7  FR3   France
8    I    Italy
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which count all values in column and later replace IDs for all countries.
But it uses first letters from country name - `GE` instead of `GR`

```
for country, count in df.Country.value_counts().items():
    short = country[:2].upper()
    ids = [f'{short}{i}' for i in range(1, count+1)]
    df.loc[ df.Country == country, 'ID' ] = ids
```